# Testing instantiation of an object in a controller_spec, then calling a method on the resulting object fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've get a controller spec that looks like this

```
describe ExportController do
  describe 'GET index' do
    target_params = {type:'a', filter: 'b'}
    expect(DataFetcher).to receive(:new).with(target_params)
    get :index
  end
end
```

The controller looks something like this

```
class ExportController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @fetcher = DataFetched.new(target_params)

    ...
  end
end
```

If I run the spec like this everything is cool. I however want to do something with the resulting DataFetcher object

```
class ExportController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @fetcher = DataFetcher.new(target_params)
    @list = @fetcher.fetch_list
    ...
  end
end
```

Now when I run the spec it fails with a no method error

```
NoMethodError
  undefined method 'fetch_list' for nil:NilClass
```

Whats up with that? The thing is that when I hit this controller through my actual app it works as expected. What is rspec doing behind the scenes here and how would I go about setting this up correctly?

Thanks y'all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `expect` statement is causing `nil` to be returned from the `new`, which doesn't have the `fetch_list` defined. If you want that line to succeed, you'll need to return something that implements the `fetch_list` method, as in the following:

```
expect(DataFetcher).to receive(:new).with(target_params)
  .and_return(instance_double(DataFetcher, fetch_list: [])
```

Comment: Thanks. When I use DataFetcher with expect in this way, does it get converted into a test double?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it", but DataFetcher.new will return a test double when passed target_params.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add this at the end: `.and_call_original` which imho is way cleaner

```
expect(DataFetcher).to receive(:new).with(target_params)
  .and_call_original
```